# File Sorting in Python

Tags: python, sorting

I would like to sort a file in Python based on numerical values:

My input file looks like this:

```
66135 - A
65117 - B
63301 - C
63793 - D
```

Output should be:

```
63301 - C
63793 - D
65117 - B
66135 - A
```

How to do it?

Comment: What have you tried? Please show us your code & we will offer suggestions. Also, is all the data in your input file all on one line, or is each entry on a separate line?

Comment: Each entry on a separate line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
f2.writelines(sorted(f1, key=lambda line:int(line.split()[0])))
```

where f2 is your output file and f1 is your input file.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this way

```
with open('filename','r') as file:
    # spilt() the line with '-'
    lis=[line.strip().split('-') for line in file]
    # sort the lis using the values
    print sorted(lis,key=lambda x:int(x[0].strip()))
```

Comment: serial downvoter ? please indicate my error so that i can learn

Comment: @Priya its not for you. one guy serially downvoted all the answers.for him/her

Comment: @Priya:  A serial downvoter is someone who downvotes everything. We don't have one here. I downvoted one of the answers, but not this one. But it's true that downvotes should be accompanied by explanations.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski ya! ur correct. i accept the down vote if they able to find the issue and learn me. there is no comment at least.this is lame. but thanks

Comment: @Priya if you got any python issue can contact me at iamsundar04@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

Here is a complete code for that.

```
with open('inputFileName') as fp:
    lst = map(lambda s:s.rstrip(), fp.readlines())

with open('outputFileName', 'w') as fp:
    fp.write("\n".join(sorted(lst, key=lambda s:int(s.split()[0]))))
```

Comment: this sorting fails . take example of 1,2,11. by this way it sorts 1,11,2 but OP needs 1,2,11

Comment: @sundarnatarajСундар Ah I didn't notice that. Thanks. So everyone uses `int(split...`.